# Python: Using Docker instead of Virtualenv

Tags: python, docker

I'm using Docker with Alpine Linux containers a lot in order to host Python servers on an Ubuntu server.

Is there a way to no use Alpine Linux inside the container, but use scratch instead? What exactly would this mean for the container, would it see the entire OS/Filesystem and any change it writes to the FS is actually written into the Docker containers, somehow like [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) would do? If I'd then install new Python packages, they would only get written into the container. If I'd do a apt install it would also just write into the container?

Comment: How are you planning to run apt in a container created from an empty image (which is what `scratch` is)?

Comment: Wouldn't it use the apt binary from the host? I mean, how can then a go binary run inside `scratch`?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Do what Sandboxie does, but on Linux. Somehow a system-wide virtualenv?

Comment: @DanielF: Commands run inside a Docker container don't use *anything* from the host other than the kernel.  Go binaries can run on `scratch` because they don't need apt.

Comment: And this Go binary, which could then as well be a C binary, is only allowed to use what the kernel has to offer?